# Send PDF file from Django website to LogicalDOC

Tags: python, django, rest, api

I'm developing my `Django website` since about 2 months and I begin to get a good global result with my own functions.
But, now I have to start a very hard part (to my mind) and I need some advices, ideas before to do that.

My Django website creates some PDF files from HTML templates with Django variables. Up to now, I'm saving PDF files directly on my Desktop (in a specific folder) but it's completely unsecured. 
So, I installed another web application which is named `LogicalDoc` in order to **save PDF file directly on this application**. PDF files are created and sent to LogicalDoc.

LogicalDoc owns 2 API : SOAP and REST (http://wiki.logicaldoc.com/rest/#/) and I know that Django could communicate with REST method.

I'm reading this part of Django documentation too in order to understand How I can process : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/

I made a scheme in order to understand what I'm exposing :

[image]

Then, I write a script which makes some things :

- When the PDF file is created, I create a folder inside LogicalDoc which takes for example the following name : lastname_firstname_birthday
- Two possibilities : If the folder exists,I don't create a new folder, else I create it.
- Once it's done, I send the PDF file directly inside the folder by comparing PDF name with folder name to do that

I have some questions about this process :

- Firstly, is it possible to make this kind of things ?
- Is it hard to do that ?
- What kind of advices could you give me ?

Thank you so much !

PS : If you need some part of my script, mainly PDF creating part, I can post it just after my question ;)

Comment: Save pdfs with default format ? Not good idea. Store pdf content as `bz2 style (html-safe)` text. Best question is how to search or recall an old outputs ? I used (uploded_csv > matplot > PDF > (html_OUT | SQL_BZ2(BASE64) ). you can create  this pdf on short time ? Don't save as PDF file, save your `variables` ! Calculate cost of `pdf` or `variable`.

Comment: It works with my method. Don't forget I'm coding with Django ^^ My question is not there, but how I can send a generated file directly in an other application.

Comment: what endpoint are you trying to reach exactly? 
Is it the one you are looking for?
http://docs.logicaldoc.com/resources/wsdoc/rest/index.html?version=7.5.1#!/document/create

basically it will get easier as you will get example of first working file transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea is pretty simple, however it always requires some practice. 
I strongly advice you to use REST api and forget about SOAP as the only thing it can bring to you - is 'pain' :)

If we check documentation, [document/create](http://docs.logicaldoc.com/resources/wsdoc/rest/index.html?version=7.5.1#!/document/create) it gives next information.

1. Endpoint we have to communicate with.
   [protocol]://[server]:[port]/document/create
2. HTTP method to use - POST
3. List of parameters to provide with your request: *body*,
   *document*, *content*

Even more, you can test API by clicking on "Try it out" button and check requests in "Network" tab of your browser (if you open Developer Tools)

I am not sure what kind of metadata do you have to provide in 'document' parameter but what I know you can easy get an idea of what should be done by testing it and putting XML or JSON data into 'document' parameter.

*Content* is an array of bytes transferred to the server (which would be your file).

To sum up, a request to 'document/create' uri will be simple

```
body = { 'headers': {},'object': {},}
document = "<note>data</note>"
content=open('report.xls', 'rb') #r - reading, b - binary
r = requests.post('http://logicaldoc/document/create', body=body, document=document, content=content)
```

Please keep in mind that file transferring requests take time and sometimes you may get timeout exception. Your code will stop and will be waiting for response, so it may be a good idea to get some practice with asyncio or celery. Just keep in mind those kind of possible issues.